# Undefined variable when running Ansible play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am running multiple ansible plays defined in YAML files.

In the last play I get the following error:

```
{"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_os_family == \"RedHat\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_os_family == \"RedHat\"): 'ansible_os_family' is undefined\n
```

Do I need to change anything with the facts gathering or something in the `ansible.cfg`?

Comment: Can you explicitly add `gather_facts: true` for that play and try?

Comment: That seemed to work! If you post it as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add:

```
gather_facts: true
```

to your last play and try.

Comment: Maybe this has changed because I don't have to add gather_facts: true in order for the conditional when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' to work. If there is an explicit gather_facts: false however, then you will get the error reported above.

Comment: @pforsthoff `gather_facts` by default is `true`. The OP explicitly set that to `false`, so either removing it or setting it to `true` will work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @helloV :

A note to self and others, `gathering =` works along with `gather_facts:`:

```
# smart - gather by default, but don't regather if already gathered
# implicit - gather by default, turn off with gather_facts: False
# explicit - do not gather by default, must say gather_facts: True
# gathering = explicit
```